# Strange Java Behavior

Tags: java, obfuscation

Firstly, this question came about because I was trying to make a hello world program (the first main method commented out) as convoluted as possible. I tried to rewrite some of it to make it more readable but maintain the strange behavior I am addressing.

Specifically, in the for loop I am trying to convert the strings to floats, then truncate the floats to ASCII values, and then lastly to chars that say "Hello, World!" The problem is that inside the conditional, in the for loop, if you have it simply be (i == 0) it will capitalize the h just fine but when you add
(i == 6) it acts really strange and ends up printing chars inconsistently such as "Hello,d!", "Hello,!" and "Hello,rld!" (among others). Can anyone explain this behavior to me? Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class helloWorld {

    // public static void main(String[] args) {
    // System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    // }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //This array is just soon to be truncated ASCII vals
        String[] nums = {"104.367", "101.432", "108.43276", "108.1", "111.43", "44.231", "32.12", "119.32", "111.24", "114.37", "108.2", "100.52", "33.237", "10.4"};
        
        //Empty "Hello, World!" string
        String message = "";

        //This is to store the converted ASCII values
        char[] chars = new char[nums.length];

        //this is just the difference in ASCII vals to go from lower to uppercase letters
        int toUpperCase = 32;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            //i == 6 || i == 0 because I want the w and h to be capitalized
            //i == 0 capitalizes the 'h' and prints as expected but adding "i == 6 ||" to the condition causes it to break and print chars inconsistently
            if (i == 6 || i == 0) {
                //converts from float to int (truncates decimals to the normal ASCII val) and then from the ASCII value to the char
                chars[i] = (char)((int)((Float.parseFloat(nums[i])) - toUpperCase));
            } else {
                chars[i] = (char)((int)(Float.parseFloat(nums[i])));
            }
            System.out.print(chars[i]);
        }

        System.out.print(message);
        }
}
```

Comment: "Firstly, this question came about because I was trying to make a hello world program (the first main method commented out) as convoluted as possible." - Why is it that you want to do that?

Comment: It started as an assignment for a class where we simply had to do the main method which is commented out but I thought it would be humorous to make it ridiculously overcomplicated.

Comment: The `i == 6` is the space, not `W`. Use it `7` instead.

Comment: `nums[6]` is "32.12", so you're basically printing U+0000. I don't know what I'd expect a console to do with that.

Comment: You're subtracting 32 from the space. This code works fine as designed and can't print any of the stuff you say it does, unless that weird control character that subtracting 32 from the space generates causes bizarreness. Make that i ==7 and it prints `Hello, World!` - every time.

Comment: Its likely just a typo, OP meant to upper-case the `w`, which is at index `7` not `6`. So `i == 7` and it works. Voting to close because caused by typo.

Comment: @rzwitserloot It is actually the space. Which happens to have an ASCII value of `32`. That minus `32` gives `0`, resulting in the null character.

Comment: That was it @Zabuzard thank you! That was a silly mistake on my part. Although, I still am curious why it did that.

Comment: @Zabuzard "Voting to close because caused by typo." - I would not assume the error was a typographic one.  It may very well be a misunderstanding of the index.  Typo suggests that author intended to type 7 but accidentally typed 6, which may not be the case.

Comment: @tothemax It kinda depends on how your console acts on the nul character `'\0'`. The console I tested with doesnt print weird stuff, it just skips that character all together.

Comment: @tothemax your code always produced the same output, namely "Hello,(0)world!" where (0) was a char with the int value 0 / ascii value `NUL`  - If that was always displayed differently on your part that's down to whatever you used to display that string messing up, not your code always producing different results.

Comment: This looks same as a question closed a few days ago, possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670108/strange-java-behaviour-when-printing-chars) but I cannot read it now

Comment: @DuncG it is. I tried to make it more readable and be more specific.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS and Zabuzard okay I see, so it must just be something different about my computer then? I was printing the output in visual studio code.

Comment: The question is indeed better now, well done.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

The bug is actually a minor one, you used `i == 6` but instead you should have used `i == 7`.

---

### Index

Let's break down what happens and why. To start off, the source string you are reading from (even though you made it `float`s, but doesn't matter) is `Hello, World!`, the indices for your array are as follows:

```java
// _ denotes the space
h e l l o , _ w o r  l  d  !
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Note that `6` is actually the index of the space   and not the `w`, which you wanted to capitalize.

---

### NUL character

Next up, you subtract `32` from the ASCII value of the space. Fun fact, the ASCII value of that is `32` as well:

```java
System.out.println((int) ' '); // 32
```

So your subtraction results in `0`. The `char` that has the ASCII value `0` is the so called [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (not to confuse with the Java keyword `null`), which is a special control character with no visual representation. It can also be written as `'\0'`.

```java
System.out.println((char) 0);
```

So when you told your console to print the null char, it might start doing funny things. Although, the consoles I tested with, simply skip the character and print `Hello,world!` consistently.

If you want to try it out with a minimal example, use this one:

```java
System.out.println("Hello,\0world!");
```

which is the string that your code produced.

---

### ASCII table

While at it, here is the ASCII table with the **null** character and **space** highlighted (from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg)):

[image: ASCII table]

You can also see that the first 32 characters are all control characters without a direct visual representation. In fact, try out this one:

```java
System.out.print((char) 7);
```

depending on your console, you might hear a **beep sound** now.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this! I did not even realize I was printing the NUL character so I was really lost as to what was going on. I learned something new today.